# Android: Storing and showing strings in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, android-sharedpreferences

I need to have a `DialogFragment` or similar with a `ListView` which contains a list of strings. I also need to have some kind of footer or something so I can add more strings to the `ListView`.
Basically it is a dialog where a user can specify and add endpoints to the app, and clicking on a `String` of the `ListView` would make the app connect to that endpoint.

How could I do this? Should I use a `ListView` with a footer? How could I store the strings in the device?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store Strings after close your app, you should use SQLite database, there you've got a nice example of use it
[SQLite tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html),
and there you could read how create a DialogFragment with ListView
[DialogFragment with ListView](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/android-dialogfragment-listview.html).

To put data from database to `ListView` you should get `List<String> someData` from your database.
To add new String you could add it to database and refresh all Dialog `View`, or add it to list using comand `someData.add(String string);`
Hope I help